# Counting Problem 1P

Tags: combinatorics

Q: A company has 134 employees. There are 84 who have been
with the company more than l0 years and 65 of those are college
graduates. There are 23 who do not have college degrees and
have been with the company less than l0 years. How many
employees are college graduates?

Trying to understand why the solution is 92. I know I have to use complements but I'm still not seeing it.

n(S) = 134
n(T) = 84
n(T and C) = 65
n(~T and ~C) = 23 => ~n(T or C) = 23

I'm confused as to what to do next

n(T or C) = 134 - 23 = 111

111 = 84 + x - 65

x = 92.. is this the right way or did I just get lucky?

Comment: Your method is valid.  If $|S|$ denotes the number of elements in set $S$, then $|T \cup C| = |T| + |C| - |T \cap C|$ by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have , in total , $134$ employees

Assuming no one is working there for exactly $10$ years , you have
$$\text {FOR MORE THAN 10 YEARS(84)}$$

$$65 \ \text{College Graduates} , 19 \ \text{Non-college graduates}$$
$$\text {FOR LESS THAN 10 YEARS(50)}$$
$$27 \ \text{College Graduates} , 23 \ \text{Non-college graduates}$$
In total $65+27=92$

Your method also works because
you calculated the $111$ employees who had been either for more than $10$  years or had been college graduates and subtracted the $84-65$ non college gradutes for more than $10$ years from $111$ leaving you with only College graduates......

Answer (score 1):

Total employees = 134

More than 10 years experience = 84

In 84 graduate employees = 65

Now less than 10 years experience = 134 - 84 = 50

In these 50 only 23 not graduated. So graduated employees are 50 - 23 = 27

So we have total graduated employees = 65 + 27 = 92